# MS SQL server management, error editing rows

Tags: sql-server

Just created my database but when I insert some rows with the edit UI, i get this error :

```
No row was updated.
The data in row 2 was not committed.
Error Source : .Net SqlClient Data Provider.
Error Message: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGK KEY constraint "FK_Utilisateur_Droit". The conflict occured in database "NewNDA", table "dbo.Droit", column 'idDroit'.
The satement has been terminated.
```

My table Droit is composed of :

```
idDroit (PK, int, not null)
DRT_libelle (varchar(50), not null)
DRT_visualisation (bit, not null)
DRT_modification (bit, not null)
DRT_suppression (bit, not null)
```

And my table Utilisateur :

```
idUtilisateur (PK, FK, int, not null)
USR_Nom (varchar(50), not null)
USR_Prenom (varchar(50), not null)
USR_Fonction (varchar(50), not null)
idDroit (int, not null)
idEntreprise (int, not null)
```

Do you have any idea about my issue ?
Thanks!

Edit :
My insert statement :

```
INSERT INTO Utilisateur(USR_Fonction, USR_Nom, USR_Prenom, idDroit, idEntreprise)
VALUES ('Test', 'Nom', 'Prenom', '2', '2')
```

Returned :

```
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Utilisateur_Droit". The conflict occurred in database "NewNDA", table "dbo.Droit", column 'idDroit'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Script of Utilisateur :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Utilisateur](
    [idUtilisateur] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [USR_Nom] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [USR_Prenom] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [USR_Fonction] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [idDroit] [int] NOT NULL,
    [idEntreprise] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Utilisateur] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [idUtilisateur] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Script of Droit :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Droit](
    [idDroit] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DRT_libelle] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DRT_visualisation] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [DRT_modification] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [DRT_suppression] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Droit] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [idDroit] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: You need to make sure that the idDroit you're entering exists on the Droit table. If you can post the insert statement being generated. What UI software are you using?

Comment: BTW, it is a poor idea to use the GUI to enter data. If you are doing lookup data, then it should be scripted so you can run it on other servers and put it in source control where it belongs. If it is other data, it still wil be done more effciently from the database perspective if you do scripts. If you have PK/Fk relationshiops, the scripts shouo be built to enter data into the parent tables first.  THen you don;t have such issues.

Comment: Yes the idDroit exists, a user was created by magic with this one.
I'm using the MS SQL server management UI to edit my table.

Comment: Pls also add the script of `FK_Utilisateur_Droit`

Comment: "a user was created by magic" ? can you explain that magic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `Utilisateur`'s primary key is also a foreign key (and `not null`), you have to provide an id value to the `idUtilisator` column which also exists in `Droit` table as `idDroit`.

EDIT:
Also (as `idUtilisator` is your primary key) you cannot refer to a single row in `Droit` twice.

Comment: idUtilisateur is also considered as FK because it is the FK of Entreprise table. (it means a user belongs to a company) :/

Comment: Than you have to provide a valid id to an enterprise table entry.

Comment: yea, the idEntreprise I set to my user is a valid id.
The most weird thing is that my previous entry had the same bug and it was resolved by magic.
The previous user I entered was : test, test, test, 2, 2
And the actual one i'm trying to is : maxime, test, admin, 2, 2

Comment: You cannot enter the same PK twice.

Comment: My PK is set as auto increment, i don't enter it. I edited my post to show you my insert statement and error returned.

Comment: I'm confused by the following line in your table description `idUtilisateur (PK, FK, int, not null)`: As idUtilisator is the PK and also the FK, you may have used the wrong column when creating the FK? That could be the reason why the first insert worked (as there is a droit with id 1 - the first autoincrement value)

Comment: The other table is Devis which is a contract. A contract has an idUtilisateur in his table, that's why it is shown as FK too

Comment: I add script of tables in my first post